# Folder that was copied from one PC to a portable HD doesn't show in another PC

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, portable-harddrive

I have an HTPC at my living room and it has a 3TB Western Digital portable hard-drive that stores all my media files. The HTPC is running Windows 7 32bit.

Yesterday I connected the hard drive to my laptop running Windows 7 64bits and copied 102GB of data in several files (each not exceeding 1.2GB in size) onto the HD. When I was done, I safely removed the hard drive from the laptop and connected it to the HTPC, but I couldn't find the folder I've just copied - it seems like I copied nothing (all other files that were previously there remained untouched)

What could be the problem? I suspect it has to do with the OS change (32bit vs 64bit) but I have no clue of how to fix this. I can see the folder in the laptop if I reconnect my hard drive to it.

Comment: I dragged them from my laptop onto the HD. I see them on my laptop and on my HD (when it's connected to the laptop), but not when I connect the HD to the desktop PC

Comment: Probably a silly question, but are you sure the folder's not hidden? One PC could have the *Show hidden files* setting turned on.

Comment: Nope, that's really weird...

Comment: How did u format your HDD? NTFS? Does it have NTFS user-related permission set?

Comment: As Andrew has mentioned, you should check the permissions of the folder. Plug it back into the laptop and make sure the permissions aren't out of wack. Are you familiar with permissions in Windows 7? http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7

Answer (score 0):

I had also experiencing like that. I have western digital My passport 1 TB. I copied a video file from 64bit pc (drag and move) and then inserting into a certain 32bit laptop didn't show up the file that I took. Both computers are windows 10 os running. So I seek supports from WD through Internet. Run those softwares that WD had provided for user. And Wahla! The video that I moved is back.